# get into the page only if the 2 $_post values

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

what am i looking for is to make me get into a page only if the 2 `$_post` values are equal to what columns in a table have, let's say i have a table  `|id|name|text|`, so when my php page have a `$_post['id']` and `$_post['name']` equal to what my table have in both of them, only then my `text` column will show what value it has inside, and if one of values of `id` and `name` are different of what my table have then it wont show the `text` value.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $ID = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : true);
        $name ='Arthur';
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql","manga");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `in-chapter` INNER JOIN `manga-list` ON `in-chapter`.id = `manga-list`.id WHERE `manga-list`.id = $ID";
        $records = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
        if ($ID > 0) {
            while($show=mysqli_fetch_array($records)){
                 echo '<img src="'.$show['images'].'"></img>';
           
            }
            
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. In this case I would include the data definitons, sample data, sample inputs and desired outputs, so tha people can find out more easily waht you are refering to.

Comment: i'm only interested in how do users get into this page , as you see i already have $_post['id'] which will make each page show different contents depend on the id the user called, i'm looking for a way to make the user call of 2 columns example: id and name, let's say i have a table |id = 1|name=arthur|text=Hello world|, what i want is , if the user calls for $_post['id'] which equal to "1" and $_post['name'] which equal to arthur, only then the output will show the output of [text] which is "Hello world",

Comment: if the $_post['id'] and $_post['name'] arent equal to the values the table have like $_post['id'] which the user called equal to 2, then i want the output to show an error.

Comment: you can use this on your query result or equivalent to see if it returned anything: mysqli_num_rows()

You  can then generate either your error or result page.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: yeah i fixed my problem, thank you for your assistance g_bor and dharman